# Is there a Javascript-based coding language that can interpret images and create downloadable 3D models?

Tags: p5.js

I'm looking for a coding language where I can procedurally generate downloadable 3D models. I need to be able to access images and scan the individual pixels. I don't need to be able to change colors, etc. as I will be 3D printing it. I would prefer a language close to p5.js but anything would be fine.

Comment: In it's current form the question isn't phrased an isolated issue related to code. It appears more of a question asking for language/library recommendation which unfortunately is not [something this site supports](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). FWIW, you can use p5.js to draw shapes and structure the data in a way that makes it simple to extract 3D mesh data (e.g. an array of p5.Vector for vertices, an array of integer triplets to keep track of faces. This can then be written as a text 3D format (e.g. [OBJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file), STL, etc.) ...

Comment: ...which hopefully can be used with a separate tool to process/convert to GCode for 3D printing. If you'd like to experiment with GCode directly in p5.js you can try [p5.fab](https://github.com/machineagency/p5.fab?tab=readme-ov-file). HTH